# react-pdf library is not working properly in react

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf, pdfjs-dist

My countPdfCharacters function results in zero characters when file is large. For small files it gives correct results.

I am trying to count pdf file characters using pdf-react library.

Here is my react-pdf Document import

```
import { Document } from 'react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack'
```

Here is my countPdfCharacters function.

```
export const countCharacters = async (pdf) => {
  try {
    let totalCharacters = 0;
    for (let pageNum = 1; pageNum <= pdf.numPages; pageNum++) {
      const page = await pdf.getPage(pageNum);
      const content = await page.getTextContent();
      const pageCharacters = await content.items.reduce(
        (count, item) => count + item.str.length,
        0
      );
      totalCharacters += pageCharacters;
    }
    console.log("Total Characters:", totalCharacters);
    return totalCharacters;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error while counting characters:", error);
    return 0;
  }
};
```

Here is how I am calling the countPdfCharacters function.

```
const onFileLoad = async (file) => {
        await countCharacters(file)
            .then((res) => {
            const tokens = res / 4;
            if(tokens > 70000) {
                console.log("limit exceeds");
            } else {
                 console.log("limit does not exceed");
        }}).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
```

Here is how onFileLoad function is being called.

```
<Document file={selectedFile} onLoadSuccess={onFileLoad} className={'hidden'}/>
```

Whenever file is selected onFileLoad function is called and then countCharacters function called inside it.
If there is any other way to count characters kindy share that too.

Comment: use "pdfjs-dist"  instead

Comment: @raman can you send me an example?